# Neural Networks gives different results when trained with a different data set permutation, why?

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a neural network using keras with a tensorflow backend:

```
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=11, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, result_train, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=5)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, result_test)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

I am testing drop-outs from a public colleges with their socio-economic parameters as variables, initially I have 8 csv files (named a,b,c,d,e,f,g and h) with 12 column headers and 300,000 rows. The result is binary, 0 for retained and 1 for dropped,I normalized the data before feeding it to the NN.

My first training set was a,b,c,d,e and f, with g and h as hold out for testing. the Neural networks provided me with a good specificity, sensitivity and accuracy of :70%, 65% and 66%.

With that I trained another NN of the same architecture as stated above this time my training datasets are c,d,e,f, g and h with a and b as my new hold-out for testing, but then the model provides a very bad result for specificity, sensitivity and accuracy: 42%, 48% and 47%, I am wondering why? Are there any published papers citing this kind of phenomenon in neural networks?

thanks!

Comment: I assume the results are for the "hold out" test sets?

Comment: @doctorlove, yes they are for the hold-out. I am trying to find out why, I calculated the number of drop-out in every csv file and they do not have a wide range the % drop out for the csv files are a=34%, b=42%, c=35%,d=36%,e=34%,f=40%,g=37% and h=33%.

Comment: Look at https://www.quora.com/Does-the-order-of-training-data-matter-when-training-neural-networks

Comment: I depends on the nn arquitecture, if the actualizacion of the thresholds and weights is online each of the training rows will affect the next row iteration

Comment: @DanielSanchez, you mean on AWS? I saved my data in the AWS running it via putty. No changes are made in the csv file.

Comment: @TouyaD.Serdan, nope, it was more about the internal neural network, maybe each previous dataset modify the next one data

Comment: @DanielSanchez, that is a very interesting case you are raising.

Comment: @TouyaD.Serdan, I made a nn library a few years ago, the order will change the next ones, but not the average in the end actually, so its no applicable in this case

Answer (score 1):

Many machine learning methods can suffer from a problem known as **over-fitting**.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) gives a variety of refernces to this.

The reason you at least use a hold-out data set is to test how well your trained model fits unseen data. In theory you could be 100% accurate on one data set and yet perform very badly on new data.

Some people use cross-validation rather than just one or tow held back data sets - this will try each data point in a test and a training set. For example with 10 data points, use 9 to train and try to fit the tenth one. Then do this for each permutation.

This can be appropriate if the various patterns are not evenly distribtued in a data set.

If one of your training sets has all drops outs, then a model predicting everyone drops out will fit this best, but will not generalise to any data with no drop outs.

It is often worth doing some exploitary data analysis to see if some of your data sets are not representative.